Power BI Power Query: can a slicer be added to reference the data connection source files' names? Source files format is Excel worksbooks?
using Power BI connecting to possibly hundreds of formatted Excel workbooks.  We would like to add a slicer that offers the consumer to filter based on file names not just the columns within the tables.  We know how to extract the file names and delimit them in Power Query and create 10 additional columns from the individual Excel workbooks being referenced.  Just wondering if it's possible to do this directly from a slicer?
Google helped with finding how to handle it within Power Query, but no luck if this is possible directly from a slicer.

No, it has to be done on the power query level.

Hi Jon, thank you for the rely.  Yep, got that working, just wanted to ask if there was a better method like a simple M formula.
